Issue with Vscode and interactive window
Currently running VScode 1.88.0 which is very new.
Here is the Scenario
Session #1:
I have Vscode open on a folder C:\user\Alastname\Datascience
when I open code in this folder and make a selection hit Shift+Enter
I get an interactive window and my code get processed successfully by the python interpreter
Session #2:
This session is on a file share on my network Z:\Data\github
when I open code in this folder and make a selection hit Shift+Enter
I get an error "command 'jupyter.runSelectionLine' not found"
I dont understand one session works fine yet the other session does not load python at all
Not even the terminal I have to manually run this at the terminal in order for the terminal to hook python
(& "G:\ProgramFiles\Miniconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook") | Out-String | Invoke-Expression
This line give me access to python on the terminal but not the interactive mode
Is there an issue with security when I open a folder from a share that is mapped Z:\ rather than local C:\
My question is how do I get my interactive mode to work on the second session that is working on a share folder?

I think this error may be caused by not adding the Z drive to the workspace trusted location.
You could try to do the following steps to achieve it：

Use shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+P to open your Command Palette.
Search for "Manage Workspace Trust".
Add your network share (Z:\Data\github) by clicking Add Folder.

